# Tilde TRUE with isalpha() returns -2 not FALSE

Tags: python-3.x, isalpha

Playing around with `isalpha()`, I have noticed some strange behaviour.

```
"a".isalpha()
>>True
"2".isalpha()
>> False
```

The two statements above, return what I would expect them to. However, now adding a tilde before, makes less sense.

```
~"a".isalpha()
>> -2
~"2".isalpha()
>> -1
```

Why does this happen? I have discovered that using `not` instead of `~` returns the output I was expecting, but am interested in the behaviour above.

```
not "a".isalpha()
>> False
not "2".isalpha()
>> True
```

Comment: Does it help you that ~True is -2, ~False is -1, True is 1, False is 0, and ~ does bitwise OR?

Answer (score 5):

From the python documentation on [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) (emphasis mine):

> `~ x`: Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1 for a 0 and each 0 for a 1. **This is the same as -x - 1.**

Since in python `True == 1` and `False == 0`, `~True == -1 - 1 == -2` and `~False == -0 - 1 == -1`.

As you discovered, to do what you want to do (logical inverse), you need to use the `not` operator.